# detect which li and hover separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to detect which li is the current and hover with javascript the right image above it separately. I made this example http://jsfiddle.net/zvkerfLg/2/

```
<ul class="box" id="box" style="margin:100px 0px 0px 100px">
<li class="inner-box" id="bx1">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="onhover()">
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/dd01lyrjx/first.png" alt="image"/>
        <div class="over"></div>   
     </a>  
</li>
<li class="inner-box" id="bx2">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" onmouseover="onhover()">
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/dd01lyrjx/first.png" alt="image"/>
        <div class="over"></div>   
     </a>  
</li>
</ul> 

var onhover = $(".inner-box").hover(function() {

   $('.over').css({"left":"0", "right":"auto", "background-position":"left"});
   $('.over').animate({width:"100px"}, 150);

});
```

I can't understand how to choose with javascript the hovered li. In my example when hover to one square box then both of them change color but I want only the specific that hovered.

Comment: I don't understand why user copy paste other's code ¿ Btw @uʍopǝpısdn first post answer. +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your selector to `$(this).find('.over')`, e.g. :

```
var onhover = $(".inner-box").hover(function() {

    $(this).find('.over').css({"left":"0", "right":"auto", "background-position":"left"});
    $(this).find('.over').animate({width:"100px"}, 150);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zvkerfLg/5/

You could even chain the function calls like so:

```
$(this)
  .find('.over')
  .css({"left":"0", "right":"auto", "background-position":"left"})
  .animate({width:"100px"}, 150);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `onmouseover` from the elements and change your jquery code to this..

```
$(".inner-box").hover(function() {

    $('.over', $(this)).css({"left":"0", "right":"auto", "background-position":"left"});
    $('.over', $(this)).animate({width:"100px"}, 150);

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/zvkerfLg/6/)

To reverse the effect on mouseout you could do the following, notice that I've removed a lot of your `.css` code because it isn;t actually doing anything...

```
$(".inner-box").hover(function() {
    $('.over', $(this)).animate({width:"100px"}, 150);

}, function() {
    $('.over', $(this)).animate({width:"0px"}, 150);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/zvkerfLg/8/)

Comment: i want the function in the <a>. after i will use onmouseout="out"

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('.over').css({"left":"0", "right":"auto", "background-position":"left"});
$(this).find('.over').animate({width:"100px"}, 150);
```

the above might work.

While in a function called by an event the 'this' will always be the object on which the event is called. the find will then get the .over element which is located under your hover element and then do its thing.